# JsonPath (jayway) to return scalar as array

Tags: jsonpath, jayway

I have struggles to craft working jsonpath (**Jayway** https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/) where property (scalar) is returned as array.

For input

```
{
  "a":{
    "b":"valueofb"
  }
}
```

I would like obtain array: `["valueofb"]` NOT just `valueofb`

Answer (score 0):

I have found an option how to do it.

```
$..a.b
```